# Continuity of series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n sin(nx)} {n!}$?

Tags: calculus

Let
$$ S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n sin(nx)} {n!}~~,~~ S_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^k \frac {x^n sin(nx)} {n!}$$

$$ \left |S(x) - S_k(x) \right|  = \left | \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac {x^n sin(nx)} {n!} \right|$$

Tried to apply Weierstrass rule for uniform convergence:

$$ \left|\frac {x^n sin(nx)} {n!} \right| \le \left| \frac {x^n} {n!} \right|$$

So if $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left| \frac {x^n} {n!} \right| = e^{|x|}$$ 
converges than S(x) uniformly converge. 
The problem is the last sum depends on $x$.
(perhaps the series doesn't uniformly converge and in that case I am totally lost)

Comment: I think the sum in your second line should start at $n=k+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your work, we have that the series converges uniformly on all finite intervals $[a,b]$, since we can estimate

$$e^{|x|} \le \operatorname{exp}\Big(\max\{a, b\}\Big)$$

So given a fixed real number $c$, the uniform convergence on an interval containing $c$ gives you the desired result.